# Notificaciones tiempo real chat en android con firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estamos desarrollando una app que hace uso de un chat en tiempo real entre usuarios (cómo WhatsApp) y nos queda la duda de saber cómo hacer que nos notifique (y suene) cada vez que un usuario escribe a otro. 
Los mensajes llegan entre usuarios, pero no sé notifican, tienen que entrar al apartado de mensajes y comprobar si realmente tienen algún mensaje o no.
Hemos visto que firebase tiene el cloud messaging, pero no estamos seguros de que esto sirva entre usuarios, y si solo son mensajes que nosotros podemos programar para enviar cada cierto tiempo a los usuarios (cómo ofertas y demas).
Si alguien nos pudiera echar una mano sería de agradecer.
Usamos firebase en android.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es un tanto complejo explicarlo pero voy al caso

para hacer este sistema de notificaciones vas a necesitar obtener el `device_token` de cada usuario, almacenarlo en `Firebase` y almacenar los `UID` de cada usuario

Estas notificaciones se mandan entre usuarios, entonces hay que usar `Functions` de `Firebase` para lograr esto

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?hl=es-419

`Functions` funciona con javascript , vas a tener que configurar un payload con la notificacion para que se comuniquen los usuarios, yo en mi app tengo la siguiente estructura para notificaciones entre usuarios por ejemplo: tal usuario comenzo a seguirte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui en functions me notifica de quien viene la notificacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer el script vas a necesitar un editor de texto comodo como sublime text, y te recomiendo ver este video para ver como armar el script y como deployarlo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TGIMLdcl9E&t

Espero te sirva !

pd: el video es un tanto viejo, por lo que functions se actualizo y algunas cosas que muestra el video ya no funcionan del todo, igualmente en los comentarios esta la mayoria de las soluciones o puedes acudir aqui si tienes algun problema con javascript

Comment: Muchas gracias, le echaremos un ojo a ver si nos funciona. :)

Comment: un gusto, si te funciona me avisas :)

Comment: Sí sí, esta semana lo probaremos y ya vemos si funciona.

Comment: Es necesario tener algún servidor a parte de firebase?

Comment: no, eso es lo mejor de todo, al usar node.js deployas el script directamente en firebase functions y todo se hace con firebase totalmente gratis

Comment: Oh genial! Estuvimos viendo que en muchos casos usaban servidor aparte y nos estaba echando para atrás un poco, pero si con eso conseguimos que si un usuario manda un mensaje a otro y recibe la notificación sería estupendo.

Comment: Si, es genial, en nuestra app lo usamos y funciona excelente, si tenes problemas con el script hacemelo llegar, yo tengo el mio hecho y andando pero no te serviria por que es distinto, seguramente necesites almacenar otra cosita adentro del push de notificacion que sea el mensaje para poder mostrarlo

Comment: Vale perfecto! Mil gracias